# Why don't the ends a switch function as a capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, charge, capacitance

I was recently reading about one capacitor being used to charge up another capacitor. In this example, a capacitor is charged by a battery, and then the battery is removed. The charged capacitor is then connected to another capacitor and charge is transferred between them. Since the wire is also made of conducting material, why don't the charges on the capacitor redistribute before being connected to another capacitor?

Comment: The terminals of a switch do, in principle, function as a capacitor.  However, precisely to avoid the kinds of effects you are describing, they have, by design, an extraordinarily small capacitance.

Comment: @Buzz Could the greater surface area and close proximity of the capacitor plates be the reason for this? Therefore resulting in the attractive forces being much greater than the repulsive forces...

Comment: Don't forget the dielectric. The switch might have a few pF at most whereas a purpose designed capacitor can have hundreds of $\mu$F which is millions of times more.

Answer (score 0):

If the two ends of the charged capacitor are connected somehow, then yes, the charges will redistribute to cause each plate to be electrically neutral. But what is most likely happening is that the two ends of the charged capacitor are not connected together before being connected to the new capacitor, so no charge can redistribute. Each end of the capacitor will continue to carry the net charge it was given due to the battery.

Comment: But once the battery is removed from the capacitor, then wouldn't the negative charges begin repelling each other and the positive charges attracting negative charges? So wouldn't the potential immediately become reduced?

Comment: @nova Maybe slightly? The ability for capacitors to store charge should be much higher than what can be stored in the wires.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the wire is also made of conducting material, why don't the charges on the capacitor redistribute before being connected to another capacitor?

First, there are two wires involved: one for each terminal of the battery connecting to each terminal of the capacitor. Once you disconnect the battery, at least one of the wires just dangles is unconnected. As long as the wire is connected only on one end, no current can flow and no electrons can move.

> The charged capacitor is then connected to another capacitor

That is a really bad idea (without some resistor in between). If there is no resistor to limit the current, you would (theoretically) get a infinitely large current balancing the charges in an infinitely short time.

In practice there is always some finite resistance somewhere, but depending on the size of the capacitor and the voltage, you can do some serious damage this way. An exploding electrolytic capacitor is NOT pretty a sight (and dangerous to be around).

Answer (score 0):

Off-state capacitance is an important metric for switches, which any reputable manufacturer will mention in their datasheets.

- Mechanical switches have only a few or even fractions of a pF
- MOSFET based switches have more capacitance, the larger the FET (the higher their rated current), ranging from pF into the nF range for very big FETs
- CMOS technology transistors also work as switches and are in the fF and aF range, but only carry $\mu$As of current